# JavaScript assignment operator - weird?

Tags: javascript, operators, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

I came across these two cases:

1. `var z = "blahblah", h;`
2. `var a = b ="blah";`

Playing around with these I concluded:

1. is equivalent to:

   ```
   var z= "blahblah";
   var h;
   ```
2. is equivalent to:

   ```
   b = "blah";
   var a=b;
   ```

This is my attempt at explaining (2):
Does it have to do with operator precedence and associativity? The `=` operator takes two operands and runs from left to right. If the explanation is correct, can (1) be explained in the same way?

Finally, is there a source I can read about 'weird' JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you didn't found anything interesting on world wide web?

Comment: @Jai not on this spicifically.

Comment: the syntax (1) is just a shortened way to declare multiple variables, they can be assigned a value like for `z`, or not like `h`. It is totally the same as how you translated it, processing comas from left to right. The assignment works differently and processes from right to left. It resolves what is on the right and then assigns it to the left part. If the right part has also an asignment, it also resolves first what's on the right. Until all the expression is resolved.

Comment: @Defaceo https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var See it just didn't took too much time to search one.

Comment: @Kaddath—but notable in that *b* is not declared in the second example. It will fail in strict mode due to implicit global.

Comment: @RobG yes, totally right, if `var a = b ="blah";` is inside a function and b not declared before, a would be local to the function, and b treated as a global (if strict mode is off)

Comment: @Jai thanks! I'll go over it and paste an answer if I understand it well.